# My DISM command appears to run successfully but nothing installs

Tags: c#, iis, dism

I'm trying to install IIS via DISM.  When executing the command either via code or directly in cmd prompt, it appears to run fine, but IIS is never installed.  I'm unsure where I went wrong.  Sorry for the block of text in the code.  I've tried running just one of the features with the same result and I need all of these installed for my purposes.

```
START /WAIT DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole
```

Comment: have you tried running this using the MS Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try running `dism.exe` without `Start /wait`, you will actually see the errors, `IIS-IIS6ManagementConsole` is not a known feature, there is no IIS6 management console in IIS7+. The next problem I got is  with IIS-NetFxExtensibility, it is missing parent features, try adding the `/all` switch to also enable required features.

Comment: After removing `Start /wait` there was no change.  Where would the `/all` switch go?

Comment: So you don't see any output of the `dism` command? What version of Windows? `all` can go anywhere, just put it at the end.